# Что такое веб-сокет?

Tags: веб-программирование, websocket, терминология

Что такое веб-сокет, это когда имеется двунаправленная связь? Сервер может связаться с приложением и приложение с сервером?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

В соответствии с архитектурой клиент-сервер, подключение всегда инициируется клиентом. Подключение к WebSocket-серверу изначально устанавливается по протоколу HTTP, после чего происходит обновление соединения до протокола WebSocket. После того как соединение установлено, оно может использоваться любой из сторон как для отправки, так и для приема сообщений. То есть любая из сторон может в любой момент отправлять сообщения через заранее установленное WebSocket-соединение.

Comment: А в мобильных приложениях нормально будет функционировать? Если допустим 10 000 пользователей одновременно будет находится а сервер будет один?

Comment: @Пётр: В самой технологии WebSocket нет ничего, что бы препятствовало подключению и одновременной работе 10 000 клиентов. Потянет или нет на практике полностью зависит от реализации сервера.